# I received a number of calls from alleged Blockchain agents asking me to give access to them through my computer to verify my banking account mines?

Tags: fraud

I have been asked to open my computer using Any Desk to see my account info from my local bank in order to send funds to my account. Is that the policy of releasing funds to investors.

Answer (score 2):

> **Is that the policy of releasing funds to investors.**

No.

Whoever is asking you to do that is a criminal confidence trickster, a scammer.

See [fraud](/questions/tagged/fraud)